# Как правильно?Придется разобраться или разбираться?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно: придется розобраться с ним или разбираться? Объясните пожалуйста разницу.

Answer (score 2):

> Как правильно: придется розобраться с ним или разбираться?

Возможны варианты ***разобраться*** и ***разбираться***. Вариант *розобраться* — орфографическая ошибка.

> Объясните пожалуйста разницу

Смысловой разницы тут нет. По контексту, в зависимости от конкретного наполнения слова *разобраться/разбираться* выбор одного из вариантов может оказаться предпочтительным.
Есть два случая, когда требуется именно "разбираться": 1) Если требуется подчеркнуть, что речь идет о многократно повторяемом действии: ***Мой компьютер уже физически устаревает. Придетcя разбираться с ним*** (каждый раз, когда что-то ломается). Против: ***Мой компьютер уже физически устаревает. Придется разобраться с ним*** (один раз). 2) Если результат может не быть достигнут: ***У вас лишний вес, придется разбираться с ним*** (не означает, что собеседник обязательно похудеет, но ему нужно попробовать). Напротив, если достижение результата критично, то необходимо *разобраться*: ***Моя группа иностранных студентов не понимает правила "Жи, Ши пиши с буквой И". Придется разобраться с ним***.

Я исключил случаи полужаргонного использования глагола "разбираться" (это см. у Alex_ander), они частые, но не с них надо начинать изучение.

Всё остальное определяется контекстом.

Answer (score 0):

В контексте "с ним" эти глаголы имеют *разный* смысл. "**Разобраться с ним**" звучит подчёркнуто *агресссивно* по отношению к "нему" (как минимум означает "*принятие мер* к нему") и в неформальном употреблении указывает на *расправу* или *наказание* в той или иной форме. Вариант же "**разбираться**" означает просто *выяснение отношений* или недоразумений, с некоторым оттенком "нежелания возиться".